# GUI not showing after installation of 8.04 on virtual machine

Tags: vmware

I just installed Ubuntu 8.04 on VMware Workstation, but it's stuck after installation.

Here's the image of phase that i am stuck in

[image]

Could someone instruct me on what to do next? I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the picture you supplied us with, the VMware workstation appears to have finished both the installation of both the Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy Heron **and** the VMware tools, which are a special kind of utilities to allow for better performance and usability of the virtual machine. At its current state, it is awaiting for you to log in using your credentials.

Consider typing your credentials in the prompt (username first, password after the username) and then type in the command line `startx`.

This should start the **X Window Server, responsible for the Graphical User Interface.**